# Can i use JT400 toolbox on web application?

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

01). I want to know can i use jt400 toolbox on web application ? i was develop AS400 monitoring program using Java swing using JT400 toolbox. i need to do same it to compatible in a Web browser. Any idea and which resources will i need ?

```
AS400 system = new AS400();
AS400 system = new AS400();
AS400 system = new AS400();
AS400 system = new AS400();
AS400 system = new AS400();
```

2). can i convert my Java swing application to web application (run as web application(on web Browser))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding 2 - very likely not without quite a bit of manual work. All swing code needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question.  The quick answer is 'Yes, you can use JT400 in a web app'.

1) The specific resources you will need depend heavily on the web technology you want to use.  Choose a framework (like Spring) and read the tutorials.  Is this the first web app the company is using?  If not, check to see what the other developers are using before deploying your own separate infrastructure.

2) Maybe [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is something you can take a look at.  Not sure you want to 'convert' a Swing app; wouldn't writing a true web app from scratch be better?

Answer (score 0):

I use JT400 in my web apps all the time.  Remember to include the jt400.jar file in your web-inf/lib folder.  It pretty much works the same as it would in a Java desktop application unless you start getting into connection pools.  Then it becomes complex and it depends on whether or not you want to have your own custom connection pools or (better yet) you want to use your web application container's connection pool mechanism.

In response to your second question, making a web app look, feel, and run like a desktop application can be a lot of work.  I have used the [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/) application framework.  If you have skills with regular desktop/windows Java applications, the learning curve is not terribly steep and it can take a lot of the hard work out.